# How to generate curl commands with the '-k' argument in Swagger UI?

Tags: swagger-ui

I'm wondering if there's a way to change the default generated CURL command in Swagger UI. It generates

```
 CURL -X
```

and I would like to change it to

```
CURL -k
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is this about Swagger UI? The curl command generated after you click "Try it out"?

Comment: Yes! That's the one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supported in Swagger UI 3.35.0 and later.

You need to modify your Swagger UI configuration code (located e.g. in *index.html*) and add the following `requestInterceptor`. In the interceptor, use [`req.curlOptions`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#user-content-request.curloptions) to specify additional arguments for the generated curl commands.

```js
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  dom_id: "#swagger-ui",
  url: "https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
  ...
  requestInterceptor: (req) => {
    req.curlOptions = ["-k"];   // <-----------
    return req;
  }
})
```